# How do I check how many rows a query will affect before executing it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-express

I'm writing an application to interface with my database (SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express), and there are two sections of the application that worry me slightly. The first involves an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Jobs
SET JobStatus = 'Running' --there's also an UPDATE where this is set to 'Completed'
WHERE (ExperimentID = @currentID);
```

And a `DELETE`:

```
DELETE from Simulations
WHERE (ExperimentID = @currentID);
```

These seem like fine statements at a glance, but if there's something wrong with how `@currentID` is passed from my application to the DB, I could possibly lose all information about which Jobs have been run, and more gravely, all of my simulation data.

How do I protect these queries from deleting/updating more than `@n` rows? The `UPDATE` should really only update one row at a time, so I'd like that to be a restriction. There's also a column in the `Simulations` table that could be used to restrict how many the `DELETE` should be getting rid of, by doing:

```
SELECT MAX(CycleCount)+1 AS numRows
FROM Simulations
WHERE ExperimentID = @currentID
```

So what do you think? How best do I sanitize these queries to prevent them from doing damage in the event that my application fails?

---

There are three tables in this DB: Jobs, Parameters, and Simulations. ExperimentID is a primary key for both Jobs and Parameters, and they are both the same size (each job has a corresponding set of parameters). There's more detail about Parameters in my post history if you're interested.

The Simulations Table stores results from a simulation at each step of the simulation. So the primary key is then formed not just by ExperimentID (as theres many many steps per simulation), but by the compound of ExperimentID and CycleCount.

I'm trying to account for situations where something gets corrupted in transfer (highly unlikely, but you never know), and situations where a simulation terminates prematurely (loses connection with DB, computer loses power, etc). ExperimentID in both Jobs and Parameters is determined by IDENTITY(1,1). Hope this clears up a bit of what I'm hoping to accomplish here.

@currentID is programmed as an integer. It is pulled initially from the database using:

```
SELECT MIN(ExperimentID) FROM Jobs WHERE JobStatus = 'ToRun'
```

Comment: If you have particular experiments you want to protect, why not wrap the statements with `IF @currentID NOT IN (32, 64, 71, ...)`?

Answer (score 2):

If `ExperimentID` is the primary key or has unique constraint/index, there is no need to limit the number of rows updated since there will never be more than one row updated.  If `ExperimentID` is not unique by itself, I suggest you add additional criteria to identify the desired row.  The `TOP` approach you provided will limit the number of rows updated for non-unique values but the one updated will be arbitrary unless your order by additional columns such that the updated row deterministic.

To validate no more than the expected number of rows are modified, one method is to perform the DML in a transaction and rollback if the number of rows is greater than expected.  Below is a parameterized example of this technique:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN;

    UPDATE Jobs
    SET JobStatus = @NewJobStatus
    WHERE ExperimentID = @currentID;

    DECLARE @RowCount int = @@ROWCOUNT;

    IF @RowCount > @MaxRowCount
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Attempt to update %d rows, more than the %d row(s) allowed.  Action not performed.', 16, 1, @RowCount, @MaxRowCount);
    END;

    COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
        THROW;

END CATCH;
```

Comment: @ijustlovemath, the primary key alone will provide logical data integrity (uniqueness) even following application or database server crashes so there is no need to also enforce uniqueness of the primary key column(s) at the application layer.  Physical corruption due to hardware or SQL Server bug is a different story, but that is detected via regular database maintenance, not by application code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is suffering from a disconnect between the wording of the title -- **How do I check how many rows a query will affect before executing it?** -- and the *true* area of concern. That title is misleading because it is assumes (incorrectly) a behavior that is (or is supposed to be) a consequence of the actual question. Yet, being the question title, that is what is being focused on.

Now, if the title was the actual question, then @DanGuzman is correct when he says:

> If ExperimentID is the primary key or has unique constraint/index, there is no need to limit the number of rows updated since there will never be more than one row updated

However, this question isn't really about limiting rows. This question is about the following statement made in the 2nd paragraph, followed by further clarification in the 3rd paragraph:

> if there's something wrong with how @currentID is passed from my application to the DB, I could possibly lose all information about ...
>
> ...
>
> How best do I sanitize these queries to prevent them from doing damage in the event that my application fails?

So, let's consider what is being suggested here that lead to asking about how to check for how many rows will be affected by a DML statement:

**Assumption 1:** Client code (app code in this case) submits a query, and while in transit to SQL Server, something happens that corrupts the query such that the query that is received is somehow different than what was submitted.

**Assumption 2:** A query that is received in a different form than what was submitted can have one of the following differences:
  * the `WHERE` condition is missing
  * the parameter value is different

---

Regarding "Assumption 1", I do not see how that could possibly ever happen. System's crash all of the time, network's have momentary glitches or interference or even get cut off (whether a cable gets cut or a router / hub somewhere in the middle gets turned off or rebooted), etc., yet this behavior has never been seen as far as I know of, or even worried about. If it was possible, I can't even imagine the complexity of large-scale systems attempting to safe-guard against such behavior. ORM's simply would not exist as they would be too error-prone (as opposed to mainly being performance-problem-prone ;-). Your query will either be received, or it won't be received, by SQL Server. There's not a whole lot of middle-ground here.

Regarding "Assumption 2", since `@currentID` is an `INT` (your comment on @MaxVernon's answer is "It's programmed as an integer.") then it can only hold an `INT`. And, the operator for that predicate is `=` (i.e. `WHERE ExperimentID = @currentID`) so not much room there for a range of values. With that in mind, here is a list of things to go wrong that simply will *not* happen:

- {missing `WHERE` condition}
- `WHERE ExperimentID = 12a`
- `WHERE ExperimentID = 37.123123`
- `WHERE ExperimentID = bob`
- `WHERE ExperimentID = 2012-12-21`
- `WHERE ExperimentID = 0x0012A7F9B21C2`
- `WHERE ExperimentID BETWEEN 3 AND 100`
- `WHERE ExperimentID > 4`
- `WHERE ExperimentID = ExperimentID`

These things just won't, and don't, happen. What can happen is that the value in `@currentID` will be either:

- `NULL`, or
- somewhere between `Int32.MinValue` (i.e. -2,147,483,648) and `Int32.MaxValue` (i.e. 2,147,483,647).

And, along with the `=` operator, the value will match either 0 rows or 1 row (for the `UPDATE`), and either 0 or the number of matching rows for the `DELETE`. It will not be more for either DML statement.

---

The only way that more than 1 row would get updated here is if *you* fail, not your application ;-). And when I say "you", I am speaking in terms of the coding and testing. Those two areas are where things can go wrong, and on that level, adding more safe-guards in the DB doesn't really change that equation. (Well, it is possible to have bugs in Windows and/or SQL Server that could have a negative effect on expected behavior, but these are very simple DML statements so the probability here is so low as to not be a concern.) However, one way to reduce the amount of involvement of the app layer is to keep the T-SQL in Stored Procedures as opposed to submitting parameterized, ad hoc queries. Then you would simply call a proc and pass in parameters, which is a fairly small foot print, and the SQL is already parsed by SQL Server and can't be altered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have working daily backups of your database.  If you are concerned about losing recently created data, take transaction log backups every "x" minutes, where "x" is the maximum amount of work-time you are willing to lose from the database.
2. Is `@currentID` defined in the app as an integer?  If it is defined as a string, and you allow that variable to be populated directly by a human using the app, you are introducing a vulnerability known as SQL Injection.  For instance, if you are expecting the user to enter '5' into the `@currentID` variable, but instead they enter '0;drop table Jobs;--' you may have a problem, since SQL Server will likely run the `UPDATE` you wrote, and then the `DROP TABLE Jobs;` code, the *attacker* wrote.

Answer (score -3):

I figured it out. You can use `TOP` to limit how many rows get acted upon:

```
UPDATE Jobs
SET JobStatus = 'Running' --there's also an UPDATE where this is set to 'Completed'
WHERE ExperimentID IN
    (SELECT TOP (1)
     FROM Jobs
     WHERE ExperimentID = @currentID
     ORDER BY ExperimentID ASC);
```

Comment: Your select is missing the column name, and if it's just ExperimentID, that doesn't even do anything, it's just selecting the same ExperimentId several times. You can use update top (xxx)... but you would still mess up that amount of records.

Comment: How should it be done? Would it be `FROM Jobs.ExperimentID`?

Comment: It should be `WHERE Jobs_PK_column = (SELECT TOP (1) Jobs_PK_column ...) ;`, if you want to restrict the `update / delete` to maximum one row.

Comment: @ypercube Wouldn't there need to be an Order By in there too? Also, is *_PK_column a reserved thing that always refers to that tables primary key column?

Comment: You have an `ORDER BY` already (I meant to keep the rest of the query the same, with that `...`). With `Jobs_PK_column` I meant the primary key of the table. You haven't provided the `CREATE TABLE`, so we don't know the table's design.